# Print within a loop in python

Tags: python

I have two lists such as :

```
list1=["read1","read2","read3"]
list2=["read4","read5","read6"]
```

and in order to generate a script I need to print them such as :

```
Programm -h -y -1 $read1,$read2,$read3 -2 $read4,$read5,$read6
```

I tried:

```
print("Programm -h -y -1 "+str([print("$"+i,",",end='') for i in list1]))+" -2" + +str([print("$"+i,",",end='') for i in list2])))
```

But it does work that way, does someone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quiet sure about the intention behind it, but it could be as simple as:

```
List1 = ['read1', 'read2', 'read3']
List2 = ['read4', 'read5', 'read6']

List1 = ["$"+(i) for i in List1]
List2 = ["$"+(i) for i in List2]

print('Programm -h -y -1', end=" ")
print(",".join(List1) + " -2 " + ",".join(List2))
```

**EDIT**:

Or even better, Thank you @Matt B.

```
List1 = ['read1', 'read2', 'read3']
List2 = ['read4', 'read5', 'read6']

print("Programm -h -y -1 " + "$" + ",$".join(List1) + " -2 $" + ",$".join(List2))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Programm -h -y -1 $read1,$read2,$read3 -2 $read4,$read5,$read6
```

Comment: Where are dollars and commas?

Comment: But the OP does not want the list items to start with $

Comment: Suggestion? `print("$" + ",$".join(List1) + " -2 $" + ",$".join(List2))` Saves you 2 extra list comps :)

Comment: @MattB. Thank you sir! :D

Comment: than you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Append the `$` in the lists using `list-comprehension` and the use `join` to create a string from `list`.

```
List1=['read1','read2','read3']
List2=['read4','read5','read6']

List1 = ["$"+str(i) for i in List1]
List2 = ["$"+str(i) for i in List2]

x = "Programm -h -y -1 {} -2 {}".format(",".join(List1), ",".join(List2))

print(x)
```

Output:

```
Programm -h -y -1 $read1,$read2,$read3 -2 $read4,$read5,$read6
```